# Generate list of copies in Python

Tags: python, list, loops, char

I want to generate list of 100 copies of the same sentence with one char modified in each copy. I am currently learning python and I don't understand why something like this:

```
def generate_copy(seq):
    copies = [seq for i in range(100)]
    for copy in copies:
        copy[random.randint(0, len(seq) - 1)] = random.choice(char_list)
        print(''.join(copy))
    return copies
```

modifies all copies. I want to get something like this: ['AAAB', 'BAAA', 'ZAAA', ...], like they are independent from each other, but I get: ['AAAB', 'ZAAB', 'ZCAB', ...]. How can I do it?

Comment: What do you think `[seq for i in range(100)]` does?

Comment: Generate list of 100 copies of seq

Comment: Nope: it is 100 references *to the same list*, which should explain the behavior you are seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how did you get result you pasted - `string` in python is immutable. `copies` is list of `strings`. So `copy` is string. You cannot type `copy[0] = 'a'` as you will get `TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment` cause of that.

What do you want to do is build changed sequence when you create `copies`.

```
def change_random_letter(seq, char_list):
    i = random.randint(0, len(seq) - 1)
    new_letter = random.choice(char_list)
    return f"{seq[:i]}{new_letter}{seq[i+1:]}"


def generate_copy(seq):
    copies = [change_random_letter(seq, char_list) for _ in range(100)]
    return copies
```

EDIT: I noticed you pass list as `seq`. If so, `copies` are not a copies! Look

```
l = [1, 2]
ll = [l, l]
ll[0][0] = "A"
print(ll) # [['A', 2], ['A', 2]]
```

When type is mutable, by using a variable you use the reference. So all `copies` elements points to the same place in memory. You need to use `copy` function of list.

```
    copies = [seq.copy() for _ in range(100)]
```

Comment: Yes, I know that string is immutable, thats why seq and copy in for are lists, but thanks for the answer. It works fine now, but I still don't understand why after i create 'copies' which are 2d lists of lists and I want to modify one lists in copies, all of them are getting modified

Comment: @BooBoo Sorry, I just found out your `seq` is list. Updated answer